# Vim full color and anti aliasing on Windows 7

Tags: windows, vim, vimrc

I am just wondering how to get VIM to run under full color (32 bit) rather than 256 colors. I am also trying to get anti aliasing but haven't found anything. I am running gvim 7.2 on Windows 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has support for 256 color themes max, but colors in themes are specified in RGB syntax, so you can set "any color you like", not sure how it will be handled. 
But judging [this](http://blog.infinitered.com/entries/show/8) theme in gVim - color support is really good enough.

== Offtopic
If we talk about Windows, its 'terminal' (CMD Shell) has only 16 colors and you can't do much about it. You could use different terminal (not sure which), may be CygWin one with 256 color support, redefine its color mapping and get nice colors in console Vim. I've tried this with console Vim in XFCE terminal (Linux), but not Windows.

As for antialiasing - think it's working, AFAICS - both in gVim and Vim in console. Sorry if you have different experience. I use Droid Sans Mono